# How does this destructuring let form work?

Tags: clojure, destructuring

Consider this form:

```
(def v [42 "foo" 99.2 [5 12]])
```

I've read that if I have to declare some unused variables in a `let` form I should denote them with `_`
like in this destructuring form:

```
(let [[x _ _ [y z]] v]
  (+ x y z))
```

My question is how does the assignment to `_` happens? Since this do not throw an exception I assume that the 2nd `_` overrides the first one but I'm not sure. So how do this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This use of `_` is purely conventional: from Clojure's point of view, it's just a regular symbol which can be used to name a local. So, you can simply check the value of `_` directly to confirm your understanding:

```
(let [[x _ _ [y z]] v]
  _)
;= 99.2
```

As for what goes on under the hood, the simplest way to check that is to macroexpand the `let` form:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(let [[x _ _ [y z]] v] _))
```

The result of the above, reformatted for clarity, looks like this:

```
(let* [vec__7 v
       x (clojure.core/nth vec__7 0 nil)
       _ (clojure.core/nth vec__7 1 nil)
       _ (clojure.core/nth vec__7 2 nil)
       vec__8 (clojure.core/nth vec__7 3 nil)
       y (clojure.core/nth vec__8 0 nil)
       z (clojure.core/nth vec__8 1 nil)]
  _)
```

So the second `_` simply shadows the first one.

`let*` is the implementation detail behind `let`; it is a special form directly understood by the compiler, to which the `let` macro adds destructuring support.

Comment: I think you partly misunderstood my question. I have no problem with the `_` I just wasn't sure about the shadowing.